# How to apply different background colour and different border colour for reusable components in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project, In that project I have a Parent component that is App.js and for that Child.js is a Child Component.

Now In App.js, I called two times Child.js. Now I have written some css for Child.js so in output two circles will come.

Now I am trying to achieve different background color and different border color for two circles

This is my code

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './Child/Child';



function App() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <Child/>
      <Child/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is nothing in App.css

This is Child.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';


function Child({ customstyle }) {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className="exp">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Child
```

This is Child.css

```
.exp {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two different styles.

```css
.exp {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.exp2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 20%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Pass the class name as a prop to Child component and use it in child component for different styling. Like below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Child.css';
import classnames from 'classnames';

function Child({ customstyle }) {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className={classnames(customstyle)}>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Child
```

Comment: Hi @Kumar Swapnil I tried what you said but its not working

Comment: Did you pass props to child components as `<Child customstyle = 'exp1' /> and
      <Child customstyle='exp2' />`

Comment: Also, you did not add `classnames` dependency to your project.

Comment: If it's possible send me your code in sandbox, I am very much confused. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: I am very Thankful to you @Kumar Swapnil's